# How to fix nvidia driver error? Unable to build kernel nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, laptop

I have an old laptop and the latest Nvidia driver supported is 340.108 for my Quadro FX 880M.

The software updater app doesn't show my drivers for some reason, but I'm running 1080p without them. I am pretty sure I'm running `nouveau`.  It gave me an error because `nouveau` was active so I turned it off, rebooted, then got a `gcc error`, so I downloaded and ran the `.run` file from the official Nvidia website.

Now, I get through the first step, but get stuck on 60% download Nvidia kernel module, and it fails. I researched this, but I haven't found any solutions. Is there any way I can resolve this?

`nvidia-installer.log`:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2jKk4PrzJp/

Comment: The Nvidia 340.108 is available in the restricted repos, so no need to download from Nvidia.  When you install from the standard repos, you also get the "glue" code to rebuild the Nvidia module for each new kernel update.

Comment: @ubfan1 It depends. For 22.04 the oldest version is 390. And it should be said in no uncertain terns that if the required version is no longer available in the repos then installing it (the normal way) using the Nvidia binaries is also NOT possible.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 22.04 I see $ apt-cache pkgnames |fgrep 340  

libcuda1-340
nvidia-340-dev
nvidia-opencl-icd-340
nvidia-340
nvidia-340-uvm
libcppad-lib340.3
nvidia-libopencl1-340 and nvidia-340:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 340.108-0ubuntu8
  Version table:
     340.108-0ubuntu8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages

Comment: Nvidia drivers should be installed during system installation by choosing the options for "proprietary drivers" and "download updates during installation".  This is the best way to ensure the drivers are appropriately installed.  After the fact, you only need to run a single command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` -- The path you have taken is quite convoluted and is difficult to fix.  Since this is a new installation I suggest that you reinstall the system choosing the appropriate options during installation.

Answer (score 1):

**NVIDIA 340.108 is a LEGACY driver which is not supported for newer kernels anymore**
However, you can try my patch for it: https://github.com/MeowIce/nvidia-legacy
Fixed for saving configuration bugs and updated for newer kernels (5.8+).

Tell me if it works for you :)